# Battery Percentage (%) Indicator on menu bar does not show 100% when fully charged

Tags: menu, battery

When I switched to elementary OS last week I noticed my battery indicator stops at 90%.  How can I fix this?  How do I know if this is an 
elementary issue or other distributions too? Because even guests in VBox display 100%.

Comment: Could be age of the battery? Have you ran three discharge cycles to reset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having some charging issues as well. I was able to fix this by either letting it fully discharge to the point of shutdown then recharge it fully to calibrate it or by letting it discharge then charging it fully with the computer shutdown. Hope either will work for you as well!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug.

Currently mouse battery notifications are prioritized over the laptop battery in Freya. Yeah, its dumb. There was a work around involving editing the 95-upower-csr.rules file, but it doesn't work anymore since the last update to Freya--I think the indicator doesn't update anymore. SOmeone put info on a cron job that forces the update, but then the indicator app won't relaunch. I unfortunately spammed the official thread (I'm sorry), but this issue makes the portability of laptops null and void, so I think its a pretty big issue and needs to be fixed.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/1315434